# How to treat str variable as Unicode after initialization for the OS module in Python 2?

Tags: python, unicode

For example you can specify a Unicode string explicitly during initialization by adding an `u` in front of the string as shown below:

```
path1 = u'./테스트'
# printing type of path1 returns
<type 'unicode'>
```

On the other hand, if you were to initialize it as a normal string

```
path2 = './테스트'
# printing type of path2 returns
<type 'str'>
```

If I were to pass the `path` variables to the `os.listdir()` function to get the files in a directory for example,

`path1` will work just fine, whilst `path2` throws an error `UnicodeDecodeError`

I tried converting `path2` using `decode` and passing it to `os.listdir()`

```
path3 = path2.decode('unicode-escape')
#printing type of path3 returns
<type 'unicode'>
#but passing it to os.listdir() threw the following error
WindowsError: [Error 3]
```

inspection of the `path` variables revealed that decoding had changed the value of `path3`

```
path1 = ./테스트
path2 = ./테스트
path3 = ./íì¤í¸
```

causing the system to whine that there is no folder named `./íì¤í`
so what am I missing? is there a different way to turn an string variable to unicode?

Answer (score 1):

`'unicode-escape'` doesn't do anything useful unless your string contains Unicode escapes. For normal text encoded with a charset decode with that charset instead.

```
>>> './테스트'.decode('utf8')
u'./\ud14c\uc2a4\ud2b8'
>>> print './테스트'.decode('utf8')
./테스트
```

Comment: If that is Python 2 you really should write that as `u'./테스트'.decode('utf8')`. You can get away without the `u` but only if your source file is also encoded as UTF-8.

Comment: @roeland: No, you don't decode `unicode`s using a charset.

Comment: @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams OK my mistake, just write `u'./테스트'`. `'./테스트'.decode('utf8')` will implicitly encode a byte string to Unicode before decoding it.

Comment: No, bytestrings aren't encoded before they are decoded.

Comment: @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams OK I'm misunderstanding that line. `'./테스트'` is a byte string. What bytes actually end up in that string? I'm assuming that will depend on the encoding of the source file.

Comment: It would. But at my console that would be UTF-8.
`$ od -t x1 <<< "'./테스트'"`
`0000000 27 2e 2f ed 85 8c ec 8a a4 ed 8a b8 27 0a`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/114805/discussion-between-roeland-and-ignacio-vazquez-abrams).